# Spring Data JPA - Order By : Sorting with Method Name vs Sort Class

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring PagingAndSortingRepository and I have a very easy findAll query:

```
inventoryDao.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"startTime"))
```

It's working fine, I just was wondering: is it possible to replace the query above using Method Name generation instead? (Somethnig like: *inventoryDao.findAllOrderByStartTime()* )

Comment: Have you tried it? See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods. In short yes it should work.

Comment: all of them are 'findBySomethnig' not 'findAll'...

Answer (score 4):

You have to use findAllByOrderBy...

As the [Spring Data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) says, the first **by** in the method name acts as delimiter to indicate the start of the actual criteria, in your case the sorting so it's necessary to add this in the method name before Order word.